# How to count the number of instances of each foreign-key ID in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my simple SQL question...

I have two tables:

Books

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| book_id | author | genre | price | publication_date |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Orders

```
------------------------------------
| order_id | customer_id | book_id |
------------------------------------
```

I'd like to create a query that returns:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| book_id | author | genre | price | publication_date | number_of_orders |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In other words, return every column for **ALL** rows in the Books table, along with a calculated column named 'number_of_orders' that counts the number of times each book appears in the Orders table. (If a book does not occur in the orders table, the book **should** be listed in the result set, but "number_of_orders" should be **zero**.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
SELECT
    books.book_id,
    books.author,
    books.genre,
    books.price,
    books.publication_date,
    count(*) as number_of_orders
from books
left join orders
on (books.book_id = orders.book_id)
group by
    books.book_id,
    books.author,
    books.genre,
    books.price,
    books.publication_date
```

That's *almost* right, but not quite, because "number_of_orders" will be 1 even if a book is never listed in the Orders table. Moreover, given my lack of knowledge of SQL, I'm sure this query is very inefficient.

What's the right way to write this query? (For what it's worth, this needs to work on MySQL, so I can't use any other vendor-specific features).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Your query is almost right and it's the right way to do that (and the most efficient)

```
SELECT books.*, count(orders.book_id) as number_of_orders        
from books
left join orders
on (books.book_id = orders.book_id)
group by
    books.book_id
```

`COUNT(*)` could include NULL values in the count because it counts all the rows, while `COUNT(orders.book_id)` does not because it ignores NULL values in the given field.

Comment: Your last statement could be somewhat misleading. The COUNT function itself ignores NULL values when it aggregates data. The reason COUNT(*) is returning the wrong counts here is because its counting rows instead of a specific column. Just want to clarify for the OP

Comment: @Fabio what is this particular query called, for counting related entries in other table ? Does it have any academic name?

Comment: @KamalReddy AFAIK this kind of queries don't have any particular name in academic world.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for this. I don't understand how the join works with the () statement. Are you able to shed some light or some literature or examples of this?

Comment: PostgreSQL requires me to include every field I select inside the group statement. `ERROR: column "..." must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` any ideas into how  to solve it? (apart  from  actually doing what it asks me to do)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT b.book_id,
    b.author,
    b.genre,
    b.price,
    b.publication_date,
    coalesce(oc.Count, 0) as number_of_orders
from books b
left join (
    select book_id, count(*) as Count 
    from Order 
    group by book_id
) oc on (b.book_id = oc.book_id)
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `count(*)` to `count(orders.book_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You're counting the wrong thing.  You want to count the non-null book_id's.

```
SELECT
    books.book_id,
    books.author,
    books.genre,
    books.price,
    books.publication_date,
    count(orders.book_id) as number_of_orders
from books
left join orders
on (books.book_id = orders.book_id)
group by
    books.book_id,
    books.author,
    books.genre,
    books.price,
    books.publication_date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select author.aname,count(book.author_id) as "number_of_books"
from author 
left join book 
on(author.author_id=book.author_id)
GROUP BY author.aname;
```