# In Codeigniter, get the count of rows that including an ID number which is primary key in another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, first ones name is organizations like this:
ID | org_name
1 - Congress1
2 - Congress2
3 - Congress3
4 - Congress4
And the other table is visitors like this:
ID | visitors | organizationID
1 - W. Rooney - 1
2 - S. Aguero - 1
3 - C. Ronaldo - 2
4 - L. Messi - 4

My problem is:For every organizations ID, how can I count the rows that including organizationsID in visitors table like that:

organizationsID=1 > row count in visitors=2
organizationsID=2 > row count in visitors=1
organizationsID=3 > row count in visitors=0
organizationsID=4 > row count in visitors=1
And that problem is in Codeigniter framework.
My model function:

```
$dbase->select('*');
$dbase->from('organizations');
$dbase->order_by("org_startdate", "desc"); 
$query = $dbase->get();
```

My controller function:

```
$this->load->model('organizations_m');
$data['organizations'] = $this->organizations_m->organizations();
$this->load->view('organizations_v', $data);
```

And finally in my view i list my organizations:

```
foreach ($organizations as $org){
echo "Organization Name:".$org->org_name;
echo "Count of visitors that joining to this Organization".MY PROBLEM IS HERE;
}
```

My final result should be shown in the browser like that:
Organization Name: Congress1
Count of visi... : 2
Organization Name: Congress2
Count of visi... : 1
Organization Name: Congress3
Count of visi... : 0
Organization Name: Congress4
Count of visi... : 1

Thank you for your replies..

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424913/how-to-count-the-number-of-instances-of-each-foreign-key-id-in-a-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model:

```
$dbase->select('o.org_name,COUNT(v.id) AS no_visitors', FALSE);
$dbase->from('organizations o');
$dbase->join('visitors v', 'o.id = v.organizationID', 'left');
$dbase->group_by('o.id');
$dbase->order_by("org_startdate", "desc"); 
$query = $dbase->get();
```

Then in your view

```
foreach ($organizations as $org){
echo "Organization Name:".$org->org_name;
echo "Count of visitors that joining to this Organization".$org->no_visitors;
}
```