# MySQL: How to count references to references to a table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Say I have a database of **publishers**, who employ **authors**, who write **books**.

Or to phrase it another way, each **book**, is written by an **author**, who works for a **publisher**.

```
publishers: id
authors: id, publisher_id
books: id, author_id
```

I know how to get a list of publishers with how many authors each employs, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424913/how-to-count-the-number-of-instances-of-each-foreign-key-id-in-a-table).

How do I get a list of publishers **with how many books** each has published?

How can I get both - publishers, each with **number of authors** and **number of books**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.`id`) noofbooks,COUNT(DISTINCT au.id) noofauthers,pub.id publisher FROM publisher pub
    INNER JOIN auther au ON au.`pub_id`= pub.`id`
    INNER JOIN books b ON b.`aut_id` = au.`id` GROUP BY pub.id
```

Comment: This gave me the direction I needed, but see my answer below for the precise working code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a three table join

```
SELECT publisher.id, count(*) from publisher 
INNER JOIN author on publisher.id = author.publisher_id 
INNER JOIN book on author.id = book.author_id GROUP BY publisher.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fire a simple sql join query for that like as follow.

```
    SELECT p.publishers , COUNT(a.authors) totalAuthors, COUNT(b.books) TotalBooks
    FROM publishers AS p,authors AS a ,books AS b
    WHERE p.publishersid = a.publishersid
    AND a.authorsid = b.authorsid
    GROUP BY p.publishersid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something similar to bhanu's answer:

```
SELECT publishers.*,
COUNT(DISTINCT authors.id) AS 'author_count',
COUNT(DISTINCT books.id) AS 'book_count'
FROM publishers
LEFT JOIN authors ON (authors.publisher_id = publishers.id)
LEFT JOIN books ON (books.author_id = authors.id)
GROUP BY publishers.id;
```